# newlfm bottom margin problem

Tags: margins, newlfm

I'm using a Long Lined Cover Letter LaTeX Template Version 1.0 (1/6/13):

```
\documentclass[11pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter}
\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.75in}{\vspace{0.5in}
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

Main body of the letter

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

It turns out that the first page bottom looks like:

[image]

and the second page top looks like:

[image]

Is there any way to make it look better?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps you should say what better means as currently this question is largely subjective and so does not have a definitive answer.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, consider [accepting it](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764) as such in order to remove this question from the [unanswered list](//tex.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid using the [`newlfm` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm), despite the fact that there is [a template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/long-lined-cover-letter) set up to use it. You can recreate the layout of the letter using the default `article` class:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{charter,graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=72pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}

%\thispagestyle{empty}% First page has no header/footer

\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image}

\hrulefill

\vspace{20pt}% dateskipbefore

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{ l @{} }
  \today \\\\%[36pt]% dateskipafter
  123 Broadway \\
  City, State 12345 \\
  Phone: (000) 111-1111 \\
  Email: john@smith.com
\end{tabular}

\vspace{18pt}% addrtoskipafter + addrfromskipbefore

\begin{tabular}{ @{} l }
  Mrs.\ Jane Smith \\
  Recruitment Officer \\
  The Corporation \\
  123 Pleasant Lane \\
  City, State 12345
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Dear Mrs.\ Smith,

\vspace{18pt}% greettoskipafter

\lipsum[1-10]

\vspace{12pt}% sigskipbefore

Sincerely yours,

\vspace{\dimexpr 12pt+72pt}% sigskipafter + sigskip

John Smith

\end{document}
```

Other header/footer content can be added using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr), if needed.